# Bash test on successful subshell command returns false

Tags: bash, test

I don't quite understand this behaviour of bash test operator. I used this line to determine if vagrant is installed.

```
if [ $(vagrant --version > /dev/null) ]; then echo "HELLO"; fi
```

I now know that this returns false (1) and that you should type only

```
if vagrant --version > /dev/null; then echo "HELLO"; fi
```

to get the expected result. But I still don't understand why [ $(vagrant --version > /dev/null) ] returns false (1). Shouldn't it return true (0) since

```
$(vagrant --version > /dev/null)
```

returns true, which is an expression (isn't it?).

From *test* man page:

> The test utility evaluates the expression and, if it evaluates to true, returns a zero (true) exit status; otherwise it returns 1 (false).  If there is no
>        expression, test also returns 1 (false).

Comment: `$(vagrant --version > /dev/null)` produce no output in case of success. `test` with empty string return false as defined by POSIX.

Comment: `$(vagrant --version > /dev/null)` is not an expression, it is simply a subcommand. Test expressions are: File type and characteristic tests, access permission tests, string tests, or numeric tests, and connectives !, -a, and -o. Test doesn't return the status of an internal command, it returns a status depending on the evaluation of an expression.

Comment: BTW, you probably want `if vagrant --version > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo "HELLO"; fi`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All these are equivalent:

```
[ $(vagrant --version > /dev/null) ]
[ ]
test
```

shells are not like other programming languages. They have 2 outputs: The return value, and stdout. You are passing stdout to `test`, but stdout is the empty string, as it has been redirected.

What you were looking for is.

```
[ $(vagrant --version > /dev/null; echo $? ) ]
```

However `[ 0 ]` and `[ 1 ]` etc all return true because `[ … ]` with a single word inside tests if the word is non-empty.
So you need

```
[ $(vagrant --version > /dev/null; echo $? ) = 0 ]
```

or more simply

```
vagrant --version > /dev/null
```